# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el tiempo verbal de tercera a primera persona?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, verbos, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

¿Cómo puedo yo cambiar de tiempo verbal en el siguiente ejemplo?

> Dios nos escogió en Cristo desde antes de la creación del mundo, para que **fuéramos** santos y sin defecto en su presencia

Yo quiero cambiar de tiempo verbal de la tercera persona a la primera persona.

¿Es correcto lo siguiente?

> Dios me escogió en Cristo desde antes de la creación del mundo, para que yo **sea** santo y sin defecto en su presencia

Comment: *tenso* significado *desconcertado, no relajado, animado*, imaginé que querías decir *tiempo* pero luego hablas de tercera y primera persona.

Answer (score 6):

Si buscas un verbo (como [ser](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Xe5Brrm%7CXe5NPsQ)) en el diccionario online de la RAE puedes darle al botón azul a la derecha del verbo que dice "conjugar" y te dará una lista de las conjugaciones de ese verbo para cada tiempo y persona.

Tu traducción es gramaticalmente correcta al usar **presente** de subjuntivo al cambiar de la tercera persona plural a primera singular, por los usos que le podemos dar al subjuntivo (como expresar deseo o esperanza, o para expresar la *idea de propósito o finalidad* con las frases que usan "para que" o "a fin de que"), pero cabría la posibilidad de seguir usando el pretérito. Así, partiríamos de:

> Dios nos escogió en Cristo desde antes de la creación del mundo, para que (nosotros) **fuéramos** santos y sin defecto en su presencia

para cambiar a:

> Dios me escogió en Cristo desde antes de la creación del mundo, para que yo **sea** santo y sin defecto en su presencia

o también a:

> Dios me escogió en Cristo desde antes de la creación del mundo, para que yo **fuera/fuese** santo y sin defecto en su presencia

Si cambias a presente (de subjuntivo) por supuesto puede ser que estés modificando el alcance (temporal) de esa decisión o finalidad y dependeríamos del contexto para saber si el uso de alguno de los tiempos no es correcto. Por ejemplo:

> Mi madre me dio dinero para que yo *vaya* a comprar el pan.

indica que la acción de comprar el pan (que es para lo que mi madre me dio dinero) aun debe realizarse.

> Mi madre me dio dinero para que yo *fuese* a comprar el pan

puede indicar que esa era la intención de mi madre al darme dinero, pero quizá yo me lo he gastado en otra cosa, o no he ido a hacer el recado solicitado.

En el contexto del ejemplo creo que hay poca diferencia (y si la hay es muy sutil) entre un tiempo y otro. En otros contextos, como en el ejemplo que he dado, la diferencia es sustancial, y no podrías pasar del pretérito al presente al cambiar de tercera persona plural a primera personal singular al hacer la traducción.

Comment: Gracias para su respuesta!